# how to i search if there is a same id in a database?

Tags: c#

How do i check if there is a same id when you trying to add a data to database?

For example, if i have Name "Leo Chan" with id '5' in the list

and when i want to add another person name with the same id , which is 5, it will show a message box that said " There is always a same id in the list"

how to do it?

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
 SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Co-op\Real_ContactList\Real_ContactList\ContactDataBase.sdf;Password=**********");
```

Comment: If you use identity columns for the Id, *you* dont specify the ID, the db supplies it - thats its job

Comment: @Plutonix, This is no good idea for showing the wanted message in the UI level.

Comment: do a sql query on that ID and if it returns any rows, show the message box

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string query = string.format("SELECT * from table WHERE ID = {0}", ID);

using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlAdapter(query, con))
{
     sda.fill(dt)
     if(dt.Rows.count > 0)
     {
         showErrorMessage();
         return;
     }
}
```

I know there are multiple ways to read from a database, but I like using SqlDataAdapters, because you really don't have to create a SqlConnection or a SqlCommand.  SqlDataAdapter does it for you.